# Android load image from url and show imageview

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-asynctask

i try to load image fro url and show imageview.i wrote code witch can download image and show it.but now i want to download facebook user image and show it.i know how i can check facebook user image "like this
http://graph.facebook.com/user id /picture?width=80&height=80
when i run programm i have RuntimeException
this is a my source

```
private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        user_img.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}



new GetXMLTask().execute((new String[] { URL }));
```

if my url would be for example http://mywebsite./pic.jpg then program working perfect but i want show facebook user image

Comment: What is the RuntimeException? `http://graph.facebook.com/user id /picture?width=80&height=80` will send back a 302 redirect so you need to make sure that you follow that redirect.

Comment: RuntimeException:An error occured while executing doInBackground

Comment: My guess is that getHttpConnection returns null because the GET request returns 302 and not HTTP_OK

Comment: what is a solution in your option. i have problem only facebook user image

Comment: The solution is that you follow the redirect

Comment: Have you went through the Facebook login process, before you try to download an image from Facebook?

Comment: no first time i  login in facewbook then i tgry to  show image

Answer (score 0):

You should be using picasso.
Add dependency into your project. And further just a singe line of code will do the task.
Picasso.with(context).load("http://somepath/someimage.png").into(imageView);
No need of writing thread and optimizing bitmaps.

You can refer : http://square.github.io/picasso/